# Check strings exist in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table A with a column named OriginalWord and a table B with a column name mySentence.

OriginalWord has rows like:

- star
- data
- checking

which stores any single word.

mySentence stores rows with sentences for example: This is a star.

I would like to list all the rows in mySentence if any of the words in OriginalWord exists in mySentence.

So mySentence in the above example would be listed but not if the row of mySentence is "This is my dad."

How do I write that in T-SQL?

Comment: You can use full-text search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `LIKE %%` predicate get rid of index usage you can use this to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  T1.mySentence
FROM Table1 T1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
       ON ' '+ T1.mySentence + ' ' LIKE '% ' + T2.OriginalWord + ' %'
```

**UPDATE**

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/483ab/1)

Answer (score 0):

For simple scenarios, yo can use the `LIKE` predicate like this:

```
SELECT 
  s.mySentence
FROM Sentences s 
INNER JOIN Words w ON s.mySentence LIKE '%' + w.OriginalWord + '%';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d84d/1).